# Django admin object already exists, when using Django 4 functional unique constraints

Tags: django, django-admin

When creating a new object from Django Administration site, I'm getting an error "Tag with this already exists.".

I suppose this is related to the contraints put on the model. However, creating a Tag  object with code - e.g. `Tag.objects.create(...)` - works fine.
It only fails in Django admin.
Any idea why ?

Note: I'm using functional unique constraints introducted in Django 4.0 (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint). I'm wondering if I shoud raise a bug?

This is my model:

```py
class Tag(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('user'))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=False, verbose_name=_('name'))
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, verbose_name=_('slug'))

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
        # Create an index to make tags unique per user and also an index on lowercase name to prevent inserting duplicate tags with varying case
        constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user', 'name'], name='unique_tags_per_user'),
                       models.UniqueConstraint(Lower('name'), name='lower_tag_name_idx')]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is the admin configuration:

```py
@admin.register(Tag)
class TagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('pk', 'user', 'name', 'slug')
    list_display_links = ['pk']
    fields = ('user', 'name', 'slug')
    list_filter = ('user__email',)
    search_fields = ('name',)
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was actually an [issue which was fixed](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33335) before the final v4.0 release.